# Locating child nodes of WebElements in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am using selenium to test my web application and I can successfully find tags using `By.xpath`. However now and then I need to find child nodes within that node.

Example:

```
<div id="a">
    <div>
        <span />
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

I can do:

```
WebElement divA = driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//div[@id='a']" ) )
```

But now I need to find the input, so I could do:

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//div[@id='a']//input" ) )
```

However, at that point in code I only have `divA`, not its xpath anymore... I would like to do something like this:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement( divA, By.xpath( "//input" ) );
```

But such a function does not exist.
Can I do this anyhow?

BTW: Sometimes I need to find a `<div>` that has a certain decendent node. How can I ask in xpath for "the `<div>` that contains a `<span>` with the text `'hello world'`"?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

According to [JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), you can do this:

```
WebElement input = divA.findElement(By.xpath(".//input"));
```

---

> How can I ask in xpath for "the div-tag that contains a span with the
>   text 'hello world'"?

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[span[text()='hello world']]"));
```

[The XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) is a suprisingly good read on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know yet, that i could use xpaths within `[]` inside xpaths...

Comment: the latest version of the XPath spec can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/#abbrev)

Comment: just beautiful!

Answer (score 6):

If you have to wait there is a method `presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy` that takes the "parent" element and a locator, e.g. a `By.xpath`:

```
WebElement subNode = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(
        divA, By.xpath(".//div/span")
    )
);
```

Comment: exactly what I was searching for in a completely other context. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

For Finding All the ChildNodes you can use the below Snippet

```
List<WebElement> childs = MyCurrentWebElement.findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));

        for (WebElement e  : childs)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getTagName());
        }
```

Note that this will give all the Child Nodes at same level ->
Like if you have structure like this :

```
<Html> 
<body> 
 <div> ---suppose this is current WebElement 
   <a>
   <a>
      <img>
          <a>
      <img>
   <a>
```

It will give me tag names of 3 anchor tags here only . If you want all the child Elements recursively , you can replace the above code with 
MyCurrentWebElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));

Hope That Helps !!

Comment: This actually worked. I don't know why someone gave it -1.
Thanks mate for still keeping it.

Comment: Glad to see it was useful for someone

Answer (score 0):

I also found myself in a similar position a couple of weeks ago. You can also do this by creating a custom ElementLocatorFactory (or simply passing in divA into the DefaultElementLocatorFactory) to see if it's a child of the first div - you would then call the appropriate PageFactory initElements method.

In this case if you did the following:

```
PageFactory.initElements(new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(divA), pageObjectInstance));
// The Page Object instance would then need a WebElement 
// annotated with something like the xpath above or @FindBy(tagName = "input")
```

Answer (score -1):

The toString() method of Selenium's By-Class produces something like
"By.xpath: //XpathFoo"

So you could take a substring starting at the colon with something like this:

```
String selector = divA.toString().substring(s.indexOf(":") + 2);
```

With this, you could find your element inside your other element with this:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement( By.xpath( selector + "//input" ) );
```

Advantage: You have to search only once on the actual SUT, so it could give you a bonus in performance.

Disadvantage: Ugly... if you want to search for the parent element with css selectory and use xpath for it's childs, you have to check for types before you concatenate...
In this case, Slanec's solution (using findElement on a WebElement) is much better.