# Selenium: finding elements in searchContext

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

everyone!
I'm stuck with following problem:
There is some

```
SearchContext searchContext;
By by;
```

which could be WebDriver or WebElement.
Assume that both of them are already initialized (and we don't know how);
Now we want to find elements with such xpath, seems to do following

```
List<WebElement> elements = searchContext.findElements(by);
```

But, if searchContext is WebElement and

```
by = By.xpath("//div");
```

it wouldn't work! (no elements would be found), because we need to do

```
by = By.xpath("./div");
```

(see [Locating child nodes of WebElements in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520294/locating-child-nodes-of-webelements-in-selenium))
But, how i've mentioned, we know nothing about how by was initialized;

So, my question is: is there any way to find elements properly despite the problems above?
I've got two variables: by and searchContext, and I should to find specified element in searchContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in some helper method which will throw Exception if this happens

```
public List<WebElement> returnSearchContext(By by, SearchContext searchContext){
  List<WebElement> elements = searchContext.findElements(by);
  if (elements.getSize()>0){
     return elements;}
   else{
     throw new ElementNotFoundException();
   }
}
```

I am writing this without access to any IDE, so I might do some errors in my example code. For instance, I think that the exception will need some parameters. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for reply!=)
Unfortunately, this wouldn't solve the problem, it's just a way to handle a failure.
It is my fault - formulation of my question wasn't clear enough. I make it more concrete.

Comment: stupid me :) Is the issue only "that easy"? Meaning - when the search context is WebElement, do you really need to find only child DIV, or is it complicated?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, there is now way to do it.
Only way to do it - is manually specify By.xpath properly:

```
By child = By.xpath("/div");
By descendant = By.xpath("//div");
```

in case of WebDriver.isAssignableFrom(searchCOntext.getCLass()),
and

```
By child = By.xpath("div");
By descendant = By.xpath(".//div");
```

in case of WebElement.isAssignableFrom(searchCOntext.getCLass()).
IMHO, it's bad.