# How to search within an Selenium WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm generating a List of WebElements with:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("name"));
```

Now I'd like to get subelements from each element in `elements`. I tried solutions like

```
WebElement element = elements.get(0).findElement(By.xpath("/x"));
```

where x is the `tagname` of each element in elements. But this searches in the complete active frame and not only in the subelements of `elements.get(0)`

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I would like to find a WebElement, which is a child (child like child in XML) of another given WebElement. What I know about the child is the relative position to it's parent.

Comment: every element inside `elements` list is what you are looking for. So you now have the `WebElement` that you are looking for.

Comment: This is only true for my example. In fact I'm looking for some special childs, which I can locate with XPath relative to the WebElements I have (all elements in elements).

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Locating child nodes of WebElements in selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520294/locating-child-nodes-of-webelements-in-selenium). It involves using a *relative* XPath expression.

Comment: That I was looking for, could you write this as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably all that you need is change the code to :

```
WebElement element = elements.get(0).findElement(By.xpath(".//x")); //this would search any **x** as a sub-child of your list's elements
```