# How to pass the value in search on url https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom, queryselector

```
driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput")
sbox.send_keys("129.226.130.245")
sbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Please suggest, on how to pass values to search box

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you can't find elements that lie within a `#shadowroot`.
You can fix this by finding all the shadowroots that contain the element you are looking for. In each of the shadowroots you will need to use javascript's `querySelector` and find the next shadowroot, until you can access the element you were looking for.

Do the following to access the search input you were looking for:

```py
driver =webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")

# wait a bit untill search pops up
time.sleep(2)

# Retrieve the last shadowroot using javascript
javascript = """return document
.querySelector('vt-virustotal-app').shadowRoot
.querySelector('home-view').shadowRoot
.querySelector('vt-ui-search-bar').shadowRoot
.querySelector('vt-ui-text-input').shadowRoot"""
shadow_root = driver.execute_script(javascript)

# Find the input box
sbox = shadow_root.find_element_by_id("input")
sbox.send_keys("129.226.130.245")
sbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

The *search* field with *placeholder* text as *`URL, IP address, domain, or file hash`* within the website https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search is located deep within multiple **`#shadow-root (open)`**.

[image: shadow-root-open-virustotal-search]

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* to the *search* field you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import time

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")
  time.sleep(7)
  search_field = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('vt-virustotal-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-auth-checker home-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-search-bar').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-text-input').shadowRoot.querySelector('input#input')")
  search_field.send_keys("129.226.130.245")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: shadow-root-open-virustotal-search-text]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Unable to locate the Sign In element within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799036/unable-to-locate-the-sign-in-element-within-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-a/62803671#62803671)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the element you are trying to search is not an `input` element.

[image: html structure]
You would be interested in `INPUT` tag, rather than some `div`. So you need to be more specific, something like

`driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//div[@id='searchInput']//input" ) )`

This syntax may not be correct, as its not tested running program. But you may want to refer this thread in order to get more precise answer. [Locating child nodes of WebElements in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520294/locating-child-nodes-of-webelements-in-selenium).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried both ways but no luck

sbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id='searchInput']//input')
sbox.send_keys("129.226.130.245")
sbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

sbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input"]')
sbox.send_keys("129.226.130.245")
sbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: @id="input" winn not work, isnt it? input is type, not id.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, the website you're trying to automate isn't capable for getting Selenium WebDriver to interact with. It could be from the security/ firewall form its side to detect Selenium Webdriver as the scrape bot or sth...  The reason why i'm saying that, because even when i used the Chrome Dev Tools to query from the Console, i was unable to get the element, e.g, getting the Search button on that site:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('search-button')
```

[image]

then it returned nothing.

I think there's nothing wrong in your scripts but the website itself.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Is there any alternative solution to get this working

Answer (score 0):

The previously submitted answers from @undetectedSelenium and @DannKlijn clearly identify the fundamental problem: the OP had not accounted for navigating the multiple nested shadow-roots involved.
This answer is just an update, based on new features associated with Selenium 4.1 which allow a solution without invoking javascript. Per: [Shadow DOM in Selenium](https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html), one can directly reference the shadow-roots in selenium:

```
url = "https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(document_initialised)  

# based on "new" features for handling shadowroots in Selenium 4.1
try:
    elm= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'home-view') \
        .shadow_root \
        .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'vt-ui-search-bar') \
        .shadow_root \
        .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input#searchInput')

    elm.send_keys('enter URL of interest here') 
    elm.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

except Exception as x:
    print('Error : ', x)
```