# Can't locate elments within shadow-root (open) using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, queryselector

I'm trying to get the content under Signers, Counter Signers and X509 Signers from https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/03d1316407796b32c03f17f819cca5bede2b0504ecdb7ba3b845c1ed618ae934/details

```
from selenium import webdriver
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Desktop/chromedriver", options=op)
details_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/03d1316407796b32c03f17f819cca5bede2b0504ecdb7ba3b845c1ed618ae934/details"

driver.get(details_url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/vt-ui-shell")
print(element.text)
```

The result doesn't include the parts under Signers, Counter Signers and X509 Signers

[image: result]

I also tried to do

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="details"]//div/vt-ui-signature-info//vt-ui-expandable/span")
```

to locate that part, but it ended up giving me

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Comment: Joanna it's under #shadow-root(open). You have to grab the shadow root and proceed from there.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Yes I noticed that. but how do I locate stuff under #shadow-root?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium This is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Signers* fields e.g. **Microsoft Windows** are within nested [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector).

[image: shadowroot]

---

### Solution

To extract the text *Microsoft Windows* you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/03d1316407796b32c03f17f819cca5bede2b0504ecdb7ba3b845c1ed618ae934/details')
  print(driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-file-details').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-signature-info').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-expandable-detail').shadowRoot.querySelector('slot')").text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Microsoft Windows
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [Unable to locate the Sign In element within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799036/unable-to-locate-the-sign-in-element-within-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-a/62803671#62803671)
- [Unable to locate the Sign In element within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799036/unable-to-locate-the-sign-in-element-within-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-a/62803671#62803671)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried it and it worked well. However, I kinda need everything in the signature part and I'm still having a hard time. I edited my post, can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Joanna Sounds like a completely different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Done! Thanks. This is my new question post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462625/cant-locate-specific-elements-using-python-selenium-and-shadowroot-queryselecto

Answer (score 2):

```
element=driver.execute_script(
    "return document.querySelector('body file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-file-details').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-signature-info').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-expandable').shadowRoot.querySelector('[class=\"details\"]')")
```

this prints the signature version information , similarly you have to find the rool and call shadowroot and find the element for other roots

https://bitsofco.de/what-is-the-shadow-dom/

Shadow dom is not part of document so you have to use javascript executor to find elements inside it

Comment: Can you explain why did not you try an xpath/css selector here?

Comment: @vitaliis you can use locator to find the first element but after that you have to return the shadowRoot from it