# Can't locate specific elements using Python Selenium and shadowRoot.querySelector()

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all the content under Signers, Counter Signers and X509 Signers from https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/03d1316407796b32c03f17f819cca5bede2b0504ecdb7ba3b845c1ed618ae934/details

```
from selenium import webdriver
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Desktop/chromedriver", options=op)
details_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/03d1316407796b32c03f17f819cca5bede2b0504ecdb7ba3b845c1ed618ae934/details"

driver.get(details_url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/vt-ui-shell")
print(element.text)
```

The result doesn't include the parts under Signers, Counter Signers and X509 Signers

[image: result]

So, in order to get those parts, I tried shadowRoot.querySelector().

However it didn't give me everything I need.

i.e. When I tried to get this part

[image]

by doing

```
print(driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-file-details').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-signature-info').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-expandable-detail.signer-info').querySelector('span').querySelector('vt-ui-key-val-table').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.row').querySelector('div.value').querySelector('div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > a:nth-child(2)')").text)
```

it printed nothing.

Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Use .get_attribute('textContent') instead of .text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the microsoft time

```
elem=driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-file-details').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-signature-info').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-expandable-detail.signer-info').querySelector('span').querySelector('vt-ui-key-val-table').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.row').querySelector('div.value').querySelector('div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > a:nth-child(2)')")
print(elem.get_attribute('textContent'))
```