# Click on accept cookie buton with R selenium

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, cookies, rselenium

I am trying to accept cookies on a specific site using R selenium. Normally, this is no issue but with this specific site I am not able to do it. I have tried multiple things, but none of them work. What I tried:

the website: https://myterminal.ect.nl/app/object-schedule

**Initialization**

```
library(RSelenium)

driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://myterminal.ect.nl/app/object-schedule")
```

**xpath**

Normally, I use the xpath finder extension of firefox to get the xpath and use the `findElement` method from the `Rselenium` package to fnd the button. I was not able to retrieve the xpath taht way, but after inspecting I got an xpath which seemed to be the right one. But after I use the `clickElement` method, nothing happens (no errors). I even tried to first switch to the frame of the dialog pop up, but this also wont work;

```
remDr$switchToFrame("ect-cookie-dialog")
btn1 <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '(//ect-cookie-dialog[@class="hydrated"])[1]')
btn1$clickElement()
```

**css selector**

As an alternative I tried to use the css selector, but this gave the same output (none, with no errors)

```
remDr$switchToFrame("ect-cookie-dialog")
btn1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', 'ect-button')
btn1$clickElement()
```

note: I tried above methods using switch frame and without using switch frame

**Mouse click**

I tried to move the mouse to the button, and click it to accept the cookie. When I move the mouse, I see the button getting 'highlighted' for a very short time (<1s) like its hovering over it, but after using the click method still nothing happens, no errors. I Had to use an offset, for some reason the **Privacy & cookie policy** button is highlighted if I
don't, maybe they have the same xpath (?)

```
btn1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', 'ect-button')
btn1 <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '(//ect-cookie-dialog[@class="hydrated"])[1]')

# I tried for both definations of 'btn1'

remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(x = 150, y = 0, webElement = btn1)
remDr$doubleclick()
```

**GetAllCookies**

Finally, I tried to use the `getAllCookies` function. I tried this in 2 ways; navigate to the page, get the cookies and apply them. And I tried getting the cookies, saving them locally, restarting R and load the cookies prior to navigating to the site, both did not work;

```
# Method 1; Directly use cookies;
remDr$navigate("https://myterminal.ect.nl/app/object-schedule")
cookies <- remDr$getAllCookies()
saveRDS(cookies, "cookies.rds")
for (i in 1:length(cookies)) {
  remDr$addCookie(name = cookies[[i]][["name"]], value = cookies[[i]][["value"]])
}

# Method 2; load saved cookies prior to navigating to page
cookies <- readRDS("cookies.rds")
for (i in 1:length(cookies)) {
  remDr$addCookie(name = cookies[[i]][["name"]], value = cookies[[i]][["value"]])
}
remDr$navigate("https://myterminal.ect.nl/app/object-schedule")
```

After trying all this, still nothing works. I know it should be possible, I've seen that the site can be scraped using Octoparse (webscraping tool) which also automaticly accepts/saves the cookies. But After trying all of the above I have ran out of methods. Probably I am not applying them well, or maybe I am overlooking a simpler solution. Either way, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards.

Comment: The element is within _`#shadow-root (open)`_ Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python/65055114#65055114) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734432/how-to-get-past-a-cookie-agreement-page-using-python-and-selenium/65735009#65735009) discussion

Comment: Thank you for replying @DebanjanB I will dive into it. I am not very familiar with HTML and shadowroot but I hope I can make some sense of it. The xpath/css selectors I took are from within this shadowroot section indeed

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution, thanks to @DebanjanB

```
remDr$executeScript('return document.querySelector("body > ect-cookie-dialog").shadowRoot.querySelector("#cookie-dialog > div._ect-cookie-dialog__links > div > ect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("button").click()')
```

Executing this line clicks the button. I coppied the JS path of the element and then I added 'return' at the head, and '.click()' at the tail of the string. I believe this is a JAVA command. I enter this string in the `remDr$executeScript()` function and that did the trick.

Comment: It would be helpful for readers to understand if you could add description to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Above solution didn't work in my case.

`library(shadowr)` does wonders! It's also quicker and very simple.

```
myurl <- remDr$navigate("https://myterminal.ect.nl/app/object-schedule")
remDr$navigate(myurl)
shadow_rd <- shadow(remDr) 
element <- find_elements(shadow_rd, 'button[class="_ect-button"]')[[5]]
element$getElementText()[[1]] #to preview the element we found
element$clickElement()[[1]]
```

In your case there are nested shadow-root's. That's why we used `find_elements` and `[[5]]` .

And how did I find that `[[5]]` ?

```
tofind <- find_elements(shadow_rd, 'button[class="_ect-button"]')
hey <- unlist(sapply(tofind, function(x) { x$getElementText() }))
hey
```

Your button is the 5th item according to the result of above code.  So it's `[[5]]`.

There's more info about **shadowr** library [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shadowr/shadowr.pdf).

I hope it becomes helpful for people whom cannot solve with above solution.