# Acces shadowroot element with R selenium

Tags: html, css, r, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape some websites, one of them has a 'Accept cookies' button which is nested inside a shadow root. I have posted a question about how to click this button here:

[Click on accept cookie buton with R selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099353/click-on-accept-cookie-buton-with-r-selenium)

However, after some help I think the problem is that the element is within a shadow root, and therefore can not be accessed the way I usually do.

website: https://myterminal.ect.nl/app/object-schedule

[image]

I have found solutions in Python and Java, but I would like to do it with R selenium, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it using R, I am posting it here since I did not find it anywhere else for Rselenium;

```
remDr$executeScript('return document.querySelector("body > ect-cookie-dialog").shadowRoot.querySelector("#cookie-dialog > div._ect-cookie-dialog__links > div > ect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("button").click()')
```