# How to handle the popup "Accepting all cookies" when the element is data-testid - Using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, shadow-dom, queryselector

So I've started a new project to help out a medium bussiness about solar-pannels that I work of ... Basically I want to take data from a specific websites with selenium and see it on my GUI that another friend of mine dealing with it... My main problem is when I open the website with selenium using python, the pop up cookie "Accepting all cookies" has been shown up and because I'm new to selenium i don't know how to handle it I've searching around 2 days about this problem and nothing that I tried is working so I assume that I'm a special case xD...

Here's all you guys need to know to help me out:

► URL ◄

https://www.kostal-solar-portal.com/#/

► Pictures ◄

[Picture 1] = https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR89s.png |

[Picture 2] = https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zirft.png |

► Code ◄

```
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

kostal_url = "https://www.kostal-solar-portal.com/#/"

driver.get(kostal_url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="usercentrics-root"]//div/div/div[1]')
cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,)))
cookies.click()`
```

► Error ◄

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Hp/Desktop/ΜΑΚΗΣ/App/open_websites.py", line 27, in <module>
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="usercentrics-root"]//div/div/div[1]')
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 520, in find_element_by_xpath
     return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1246, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="usercentrics-root"]//div/div/div[1]"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element <kbd>Accept All</kbd> is within [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector).

[image: kostal]

---

### Solution

To click on <kbd>Accept All</kbd> you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.kostal-solar-portal.com/#/")
  time.sleep(5)
  element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")""")
  element.click()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Can't locate elments within shadow-root (open) using Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445170/cant-locate-elments-within-shadow-root-open-using-python-selenium/65452620#65452620)
- [How to get past a cookie agreement page using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734432/how-to-get-past-a-cookie-agreement-page-using-python-and-selenium/65735009#65735009)

Comment: Thank you saved my day literally!... By the way that #shadow-root(open) link that you put there is written in Java so I just went straight up to your code block and copy all of it xD... All though I'm having a question seeing the below answer if i leave the driver.implicity_wait(10) should I'll be able to remove the sleep method?

Comment: @Thomas Checkout the other embedded links and references as well. I'm not sure, but `implicity_wait()` may not be effective here, but still you may like to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

The element you trying to access is inside the Shadow Root.
So you first need to get inside that shadow root and then get the "Accept cookies" element.
You should also improve your locators.
This should work:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
kostal_url = "https://www.kostal-solar-portal.com/#/"
driver.get(kostal_url)
shadow_section = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', find_element_by_id("usercentrics-root")) 
shadow_section.find_element_by_css('button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your time... But I found more simple the above answer! :*

Comment: His answer is not simpler, it just combines 2 actions in 1 complex JavaScript script...

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm not sure. At least sometimes it makes code less clear and harder for debugging. In this specific case I don't know what approach is better.