# How to interact with Cookie pop within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, shadow-dom, queryselector

I would like to scrap immowelt.de, but I could not get pass the cookie banner.
I tried to wait for the banner to load using both sleep() and WebDriverWait, however none of them is working.

This is the code with the webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_driver_path = '.../chromedriver'
url = 'https://www.immowelt.de/immobilienpreise'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/button'))).click()

driver.close()
```

And this is the code with sleep

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_driver_path = '.../chromedriver'
url = 'https://www.immowelt.de/immobilienpreise'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/button').click()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element <kbd>OK</kbd> is within [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56380091/7429447).

[image: immobilienpreise]

---

### Solution

To click on <kbd>OK</kbd> you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763793/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.immowelt.de/immobilienpreise")
  time.sleep(5)
  element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")""")
  element.click()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to handle the popup "Accepting all cookies" when the element is data-testid - Using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70347683/7429447)
- [Can't locate elments within shadow-root (open) using Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452620/7429447)
- [How to get past a cookie agreement page using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65735009/7429447)