# Access shadow root content with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, css-selectors, shadow-dom

I'm trying to accept the cookie pop up on http://www.immobilienscout24.de.
I'm using selenium 4.61, webdriver-manger with chrome, python 3.11 and Fedora 37, but I'm always getting an error.

I'm using the following code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

def accept_cookies():
    shadow_root = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#usercentrics-root"))).shadow_root
    shadow_root.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "sc-gsDKAQ fWOgSr")).click()

url = 'http://www.immobilienscout24.de/'

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

accept_cookies()
```

The sleeping is only done to have the cookie pop up loaded.
Error is: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string on shadow_root.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-gsDKAQ fWOgSr'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```py
url = "http://www.immobilienscout24.de/"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")""")
element.click()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, i guess i have to look more into scripting

Comment: Yup. See here for more explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71056513/3485434

Comment: yes, i had to wait 5 min after it was answered

Comment: Sure. It is my pleasure to help here :)