# The Buttons I am trying to highlight through an XPath are not being highlighted, despite copying it directly from the inspect element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, reddit

I'm trying to get Python Selenium to press the button by finding the certain element from the XPATH. I have been able to do this for other instances, but this particular one is being weird and I don't understand why.

So to help visualize what's going on, I'm using the Google Chrome extension "XPath Helper". But even when I copy the XPath directly from the inspect element page and paste it, it comes out as null. Below is a screenshot as well as a link to the subreddit post I'm using. I just want to find all the elements with that minus symbol, the `"comment-fold-button"`

The page is being accessed with no account. I am not logged in intentionally.

[link to subreddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/14d94rx/why_cant_cashiers_have_chairs/)

[Screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ4pK.png)

So to help visualize what's going on, I'm using the Google Chrome extension "XPath Helper". But even when I copy the XPath directly from the inspect element page and paste it, it comes out as null. Above is a screenshot as well as a link to the subreddit post I'm using. I just want to find all the elements with that minus symbol, the `"comment-fold-button"`

Answer (score 0):

The desired `<button>` elements are within [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447):

[image: multipleShadowRoot]

So [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) can find those elements readily.

---

### Solution

You need to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71056513/7429447) command to locate the elements as follows:

```
document.querySelector('shreddit-comment').shadowRoot.querySelector('#comment-fold-button')
```

Console snapshot:

[image: comment-fold-button]