# Selenium can not find Accept All cookies button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a web scraper, which tries to scrape this side.
However when accessing it, a Accept Cookies Windows opens. The button has the following HTML code:

```
<button role="button" data-testid="uc-accept-all-button" class="sc-dcJsrY jwpeOB" style="margin: 0px 6px;">Alle akzeptieren</button>
```

My script looks like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.hornbach.de"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
accept_cookies_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[3]')))
accept_cookies_button.click()
```

The Cookie window with the accept button pops up, but the whole process exits after the timeout I have set with the following error:

```
    accept_cookies_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[3]')))
  File "/Users/..../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001042b5ed8 chromedriver + 5091032
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001042acc43 chromedriver + 5053507
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000103e48527 chromedriver + 447783
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000103e97339 chromedriver + 770873
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000103e974f1 chromedriver + 771313
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000103edd304 chromedriver + 1057540
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000103ebe68d chromedriver + 931469
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000103eda6e1 chromedriver + 1046241
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000103ebe433 chromedriver + 930867
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000103e89042 chromedriver + 712770
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000103e8a26e chromedriver + 717422
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000104277439 chromedriver + 4834361
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010427c5dd chromedriver + 4855261
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000104283572 chromedriver + 4883826
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010427d30d chromedriver + 4858637
15  chromedriver                        0x000000010424f16c chromedriver + 4669804
16  chromedriver                        0x000000010429bcd8 chromedriver + 4984024
17  chromedriver                        0x000000010429be90 chromedriver + 4984464
18  chromedriver                        0x00000001042ac87e chromedriver + 5052542
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81a3894e1 _pthread_start + 125
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81a384f6b thread_start + 15
```

Has anybody got a clue why it can not be found, even though it visually appears? I have also tried it with CSS selectors instead of XPATH but the same happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055919/how-to-interact-with-cookie-pop-within-shadow-root-open-using-selenium

Comment: There are far easier/quicker ways to get the product/store data than using selenium. If you inspect the Network tab of the browser as you navigate the website you can see endpoints to an API that will serve you the data you want.