# Using python and Selenium to scrape the innerText within an HTML element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wrote a script that uses the selenium and pyautogui modules to login and scrape a value from an element and print it, but it's printing two dashes `--`.

Here is the HTML that contains the value 417 which I want to retrieve:

```
<p id="totReqCountVal" class="trailer-0 avenir-regular font-size-4 text-green js-total-requests">417</p>
```

This is the relevant code I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser.get('website_to_be_scraped')
browser.find_element(By.ID, 'totReqCountVal')
```

I then tried:

```
views = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'totReqCountVal')
    print(views)
```

which returns:

```
(session="12e48df447f7df855a1ee596ba609a30", element="1027ec31-8cb8-4758-b4b0-82b85628ed6c")
```

With some help I have also tried the following:

Using CSS_SELECTOR and text attribute:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p#totReqCountVal[class$='js-total-requests']"))).text)
Using XPATH and get_attribute("innerHTML"):

print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@id='totReqCountVal' and contains(@class, 'js-total-requests')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

added the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I have checked through devtools if the locator strategies identifies the element uniquely, checked for iframes, and shadow root.

How do I retrieve the 417 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`views` is the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) which on printing rightly prints:

```
(session="12e48df447f7df855a1ee596ba609a30", element="1027ec31-8cb8-4758-b4b0-82b85628ed6c")
```

---

### Solution

To print the text ***417*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p#totReqCountVal[class$='js-total-requests']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@id='totReqCountVal' and contains(@class, 'js-total-requests')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Any reason why both Locator strategies print just two dashes, `--` instead of 417?

Comment: Check through [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702281/7429447) if the [_locator strategies_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447) identifies the element uniquely.

Comment: I checked the devtools and copied the CSSSelector which is: `#totReqCountValf`. I also checked the Xpath: `//*[@id='totReqCountVal']`. The only difference between this and the ones in the provided solution is the change from 'p' to '*'. Not sure how I would check if it's unique though.

Comment: Check the number of matches in the right side bottom. It should be 1 of 1 matches.

Comment: okay, I have 1 of 1 match for both //*[@id=`'totReqCountVal']` and `#totReqCountVal` when using CTRL-F to search within the devtools

Comment: Check if the element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)

Comment: Checked and the element is not within an `<iframe`

Comment: Check for [**shadow root**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70347683/7429447) as well

Comment: shadow root doesn't seem to be an issue here

Comment: Could the issue be that the number is dynamically generated rather than hardcoded?

Comment: Turns out it I needed to increase the seconds for time.sleep as it was scraping before the value was generated.