# Cant find placeholder element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've trying to find the element 'Search' in the code above, but everytime I receive Unable to locate element. I already tried with xpath and css

```
<div class="wrapper-customer-search">
    <search-customers class="hydrated">
        #shadow-root (open)
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </search-customers>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *`<input>`* element with placeholder value as ***Search*** is within [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56380091/7429447).

---

### Solution

To locate the element you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763793/7429447) and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  time.sleep(3)
  element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('search-customers').shadowRoot.querySelector("input[placeholder='Search']")""")
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to handle the popup "Accepting all cookies" when the element is data-testid - Using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70347683/7429447)

Comment: I received this message:
```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')
```

Comment: @haraujo Updated the answer adding a wait for the _**shadowRoot**_ to render.

Comment: now I have this error:
Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')

Comment: @haraujo Checkout the updated answer I have added a relevant reference. Let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using **io.github.sukgu** that helps you to work on the shadow elements. I was able to automate the scenario that you mentioned. Below is the detailed code.

Step 1 add the below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.sukgu/automation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.sukgu</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 2 use the below import in the test file

```
import io.github.sukgu.*;
```

Step 3 Below is the entire code that worked for me

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("<your_webpage>");
        

        Shadow shadow = new Shadow(driver);
        WebElement searchField = shadow.findElement("input[placeholder='Search']");
```

Comment: not working for me, I'm using python