# How to extract info within a #shadow-root (open) using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, queryselector

I got the next url related to an online store https://www.tiendasjumbo.co/buscar?q=mani and I can't extract the product label an another fields:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from random import randint

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= "C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(4)

url =  "https://www.tiendasjumbo.co/buscar?q=mani"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="impulse-title"]')
```

What am I doing wrong, I also tried to switch the iframes but there is no way to achieve my goal? any help is welcome.[image]

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Show us what you are trying to get from the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The products within the website https://www.tiendasjumbo.co/buscar?q=mani are located within a **`#shadow-root (open)`**.

[image: impulse-search]

---

### Solution

To extract the product label you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tiendasjumbo.co/buscar?q=mani')
  item = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('impulse-search').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.group-name-brand h1.impulse-title span.formatted-text')")
  print(item.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  La especial mezcla de nueces, maní, almendras y marañones x 450 g
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Unable to locate the Sign In element within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799036/unable-to-locate-the-sign-in-element-within-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-a/62803671#62803671)
- [How to locate the First name field within shadow-root (open) within the website https://www.virustotal.com using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864415/how-to-locate-the-first-name-field-within-shadow-root-open-within-the-website/62865411#62865411)

---

### Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome version 96

Chrome v96 has changed the shadow root return values for Selenium. Some helpful links:

- [Java - full example on GitHub](https://github.com/titusfortner/website-examples/blob/shadow_dom/java/selenium4/src/test/java/com/titusfortner/selenium4/ShadowDomTest.java#L93-L95)
- [Shadow DOM in Selenium](https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html)
- [Python - full example on GitHub](https://github.com/titusfortner/website-examples/blob/shadow_dom/python/selenium4/tests/test_shadow_dom.py#L79-L81)
- [Shadow DOM and Selenium with Chromium 96](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/shadow-dom-selenium-chromium-96-titus-fortner/?trk=public_profile_article_view)
- [C# - full example on GitHub](https://github.com/titusfortner/website-examples/blob/shadow_dom/dotnet/Selenium4/ShadowDomTest.cs#L103-L105)
- [Shadow DOM in Ruby Selenium](https://medium.com/@titus_on_testing/shadow-dom-in-ruby-selenium-6703dd99e549)
- [Ruby - full example on GitHub](https://github.com/titusfortner/website-examples/blob/shadow_dom/ruby/selenium4/spec/shadow_dom_spec.rb#L51-L53)