# Unable to click "Accept all" cookies in Selenium(python) in a pop-up

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click the Accept button on the pop-up for cookies.
Here's the code that I have tried:

```
driver.get(r'https://www.studydrive.net/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.sc-gtsrHT.iETHdM"))).click()
```

Here's the error:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have also tried using X-path but was not able to click on the button.
Any help is highly appreeciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pop-up is on the `shadow dom`.
Selenium does not provide explicit support to work with Shadow DOM elements, as they are not in the current dom. That's the reason why we will get `NoSuchElementException` exception when try to access the elements in the `shadow dom.
With the following JavaScript this should work:

```
driver.get(r'https://www.studydrive.net/')
time.sleep(5)
accept_all_btn = driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[aria-label="Accept All"]')''')
accept_all_btn.click()
```

See more explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python)