# How to click an element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have a problem with clicking an element using XPath in selenium. Here is the HTML element for the problem :

```
<label for="file" class="pb default" style="display: inline-block;margin: 5px 10px;">Select File</label>
```

Do you know the solution for this? Any response is really appreciated.

**UPDATE :**

here is the whole source code for the problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <BASE HREF="http://1.1.1.19/webclient/utility">
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="../webclient/skins/skins-20190807-1904/iot18/css/filex.css">
</head>
<body style="background: transparent; background-color: transparent">
<form name="IMPORT" id="IMPORT" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" NAME="componetId" VALUE="itemimage_3_1-if">
    <input type="hidden" NAME="controlId" VALUE="itemimage_3_1">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="maintable">
        <tr>

            <td align="left"  style="white-space: nowrap;">

                    <label for="file" class="pb default" style="display: inline-block;margin: 5px 10px;">Select File</label>
                    <input id="fileName" onmousedown="" type="text" value="" class="fld fld_ro text ib" readonly size="50"/> 
                
                <input id="file" type="file" name="value" title="Specify a New File" onchange="" size="35" class="text"  style="    width: 0.1px;height: 0.1px !important;fileStyle: 0;overflow: hidden;position: absolute;z-index: -1;opacity: 0;" value="" onclick="if(!parent.undef(parent.firingControl) && parent.firingControl.id==this.id){parent.sendEvent('clientonly','clickFileButton', this.id)}">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e){
        document.querySelector('#fileName').value = e.currentTarget.files[0].name;
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: please describe the problem you're having: what error message or result do you get? what Selenium method did you call? what xpath expression do you use?

Comment: i am using the usual method that is explained in selenium documentation...i can make it work on all of my programs, except this part

Comment: i am using this : input_func=_brw_.find_element_by_xpath(id)

Answer (score 1):

Can try with `//label[@for='file']` or `//label[@for='file'][text()='Select File']`

If this is not working maybe you are targeting the wrong element or you are not waiting enough before it appears. When dealing with uploading files, I target the input with type file //input[@type='file'], not the label, you may need to provide bigger part of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

if **class=pb default** is a unique class in the web-page then try this out.

```
driver.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="pb default"]').click()
```

or you can search by text **Select File**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),"Select File")]').click()
```

Comment: i have tried that but the error is like this : "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@class="pb default"]"

Comment: @DeadlyKitten999 can you send me the page url?

Comment: the web is for internal use so it is inaccessible using regular connection..

Answer (score 0):

Well **No**, you don't click on a `<label>` element. However, you may require to locate the `<label>` element for other purposes.

---

To identify the `<label>` element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.pb.default[for='file']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@class='pb default' and text()='Select File']")
  ```

---

### Update

Element can be within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) or within a [`#shadow-root`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447). Otherwise the locator works perfecto:

[image: label]

Comment: thx for the response..i have tried your code but i come across this error :
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //label[@class='pb default' and text()='Select File']