# C# Selenium: How to click on the button which is inside a shadow-root (open) and has a data-testid attribute

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, queryselector, shadow-root

I am working with C# and Selenium and am trying to press this button.

[image]

I tried a lot of ways to click on this butten. But Selenium seem not able to find the element.
My latest try is

```
IWebElement clickableButton = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='uc - center - container']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[1]"));
clickableButton.Click();
```

However, all tries lead to the fault:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='uc - center - container']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[1]"}
```

How can I press this button?

Let me know if more/further information is helpful to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The `<button>` element is within a [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447)

[image: shadow-root]

---

### Solution

To click on the `<button>` element you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('div#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[data-testid=\"uc-customize-button\"]')"))).Click();
```

Comment: It brought me one step further. But still it looks like the element does not get located. However I am still glad, that I now understand, that Selenium seems to have some issues to locate a shadow-root element. 

I get the error:  Test method WithDotNet.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds
--> I think it is still not finding the element

Comment: Check in the `Development Tools` -> `Console` if executing the command `return document.querySelector('div#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[data-testid=\"uc-customize-button\"]')` identifies the element uniquely.

Comment: I get the message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()"
However the website does load, I can see the butten, and I can also press is manually.

Comment: _I can see the butten, and I can also press is manually_: That wasn't my question either. Please reread my question again.

Comment: Without seeing the actual shadowRoot I think we have reached to a dead-lock now

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure how to answer your question. I think I get it now. Hopefully.

Comment: I get the error(s)
"JSError t=1659776828184&level=ERRO&source=onerror&fileName=https%3A%..."
and
"VM2917:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"

Comment: an update:
the following works in the developer tools console:
document.querySelector("#usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uc-center-container > div.sc-bYoBSM.jvautU > div > div > div > div > button.sc-gsDKAQ.iVBeYE").click()

Comment: @Phill Honestly, we can't improve our answer as we were unable to test our answer before publishing. That's why on SO we recommend the text based HTML instead of a snapshot.

Comment: Totally understandable. I appreciate all the effort. I really do. However I do not know how to copy the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I found a documentation in git saying this is a current known issue/bug/white-spot in Selenium for C# (Can't find the link anymore).

Anyhow, I was able to click the button with Java.

```java
JavascriptExecutor jse =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = (WebElement)jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector(\"#usercentrics-root\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#uc-center-container > div.sc-bYoBSM.jvautU > div > div > div > button.sc-gsDKAQ.iVBeYE\")");
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code without JavaScript

```cs
IWebElement shadowHost = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("usercentrics-root"));
ISearchContext shadowRoot = shadowHost.GetShadowRoot();
IWebElement clickableButton = shadowRoot.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[data-testid='uc-customize-button']"));
clickableButton.Click();
```

In shadow root you can find any element with `CssSelector` only.