# How to accept cookies popup within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom, queryselector

I am trying to press the **accept** button in a cookies popup in the website `https://www.immobilienscout24.de/`

Snapshot:

[image]

I understand that this requires

```
driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root')""")
```

But I can't trickle down the path to the **accept** button in order to click it. Can anyone provide some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element <kbd>Alle akzeptieren</kbd> within the [website](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/) is located within a [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python).

[image: shadow_root]

---

### Solution

To click on the element <kbd>Alle akzeptieren</kbd> you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763793/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/'})
  time.sleep(10)
  item = driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector('div#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')''')
  item.click()
  ```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way (tested & working) you can click that button: please observe the imports, as well as the code after defining the browser/driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
import time as t


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

actions = ActionChains(browser)

url = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen'

browser.get(url) 

page_title = WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Zur Homepage']")))
actions.move_to_element(page_title).perform()
parent_div = WebDriverWait(browser, 20000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "usercentrics-root"))) 
shadowRoot = browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", parent_div)

try:
    button = WebDriverWait(shadowRoot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']"))) 
    button.click()
    print('clicked')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('no click button')
```

That page is reacting to user's behavior, and it will only fully load the page once it detects mouse movements, hence the `ActionChains()` part of the code. After that, we drill down into the `shadow root` element, we locate the button (using Waits, to make sure it's clickable), and then we click it.

Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/