# Watir: select an element with multiple custom attributes

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

When creating a Watir script that clicks a right pagination arrow, I can't seem to find a solution to grabbing the bottom 'kat-icon' tag: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYFKR.jpg

Tried using a lot of different versions of the line below but nothing seems to work.

```
browser.element(id: 'mas-apps-store-search-paginator').span(name: 'chevron-right').exists?
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of HTML are not. Please post the relevant HTML as text in your question and properly format it.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try a simple CSS selector like

```
#mas-apps-store-search-paginator kat-icon[name='chevron-right']
```

I'm kinda assuming that won't work due to the `shadow-root`. In that case, you'd need to do something like

```
shadow_host = driver.find_element(id: 'mas-apps-store-search-paginator')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
icon = shadow_root.find_element(name: 'chevron-right')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

[image: kat-icon]

the *`<kat-icon>`* element is within a [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447)

---

### Solution

To identify and click on the *`<kat-icon>`* element you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
shadow_host = browser.find_element(css: 'kat-pagination.mas-paginator')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
right_pagination_arrow = shadow_root.find_element(css: 'kat-icon.nav__icon[name="chevron-right"]')
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. How do I translate it into Watir though? Sorry if it's a basic question but it's the first time I come across 'driver'.

Comment: Never mind, just figured it out and it works perfectly. Only needed to add 'browser.' in front of 'driver'

Comment: @alvaro88 Yeap, that was the only change you needed.