# How to find element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Just starting to learn selenium using python and running into trouble with the basics of finding elements.  This is a search/text box that I am trying to click into and send text to it.

Here is the code of the element I got from Edge.

```
<div class="box" id="ClinicSrch" style="display:block">
  <span align="lb">Last:</span> 
<input type="search" name="NameLast" size="15" class="white1" value="" maxlength="25">
  &nbsp;First: <input type="search" name="NameFirst" size="15" class="white1" value="" maxlength="25"><br>
```

Here is my code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ClinicSrch"]/input[1]').click()
```

The xpath that I get when copying the element from edge inspect tool is:

```
//*[@id="ClinicSrch"]/input[1]
```

Full xpath is:

```
/html/body/form/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]
```

I've been trying with other fields and buttons where I have similar xpaths but nothing is working.  I always get no such element.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the **Last Name** *search field* you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#PtSrchFrame[name='PtSrchFrame']")))
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='NameLast']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='PtSrchFrame' and @name='PtSrchFrame']")))  
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='NameLast']")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate the **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#PtSrchFrame[name='PtSrchFrame']")))
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='NameLast']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='PtSrchFrame' and @name='PtSrchFrame']")))      
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='NameLast']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I added the imports you suggested.  However, I still get the same no such element message when using CSS _Selector or the Xpath you suggested.  I feel like I have tried it 500 different ways.

Comment: Did you try with the code in the second part?

Comment: Yes, and it throws a timeout exception error when I use the ones with webdriverwait.  These are the most recent ones I have tried.  
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='NameLast']")))
#element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='NameLast']")
#driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ClinicSrch"]/input[1]').click()
#ptsearch.send_keys("able")
#lastname = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "NameLast").send_keys("able")
#driver.find_element(By.ID, "NameFirst").send_keys("larry")

Comment: Any other suggestions on things I can try? I still cannot make headway.  Any other info you need that I could be leaving out?

Comment: See there are n number of other things among which one factor is blocking your test. If you can figure out what exactly blocking you I can bring out a solution. Watch the DOM carefully incase you can dig out the desired element is within an [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) or a [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447)

Comment: Now that you say that, it most likely is in an iframe.  How could I go about finding out if that is the case or what to do.  Not sure where to start.  Thank you!

Comment: Alright, that whole page appears to be contained within an iframe.  Here is the iframe it is in, will this help?  <iframe title="Main Content" name="MSMainIntro" frameborder="0" src="Index_Main.asp"></iframe>

Comment: @WeDoneLost Any thing preventing you from visiting the embedded links within my comments? Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: Sorry that is incorrect, this is the iframe the specific element I need to find is in.  <iframe id="PtSrchFrame" name="PtSrchFrame" style="display: block; max-width: 500px; min-width: 380px; width: 80%; z-index: 100; overflow: auto; max-height: 154px; height: 154px;" onload="adjDispFrame('PtSrchFrame',500)" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="NO" src="/DocSynergy/CentralMR/PatientProfile/PtSubscrSearch.asp?SrchType=Pt"></iframe>

Comment: I am just trying to get started learning this and can't find a single element on the site I need to use this for.  I guess I need to research how to find elements inside an iframe?

Comment: Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I tried both and but getting the same timeout exception as before.     File "C:\Users\jcoleman\PycharmProjects\pythonproject1\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='PtSrchFrame' and @name='PtSrchFrame']")))
  File "C:\Users\jcoleman\PycharmProjects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: Also looking closer inspecting this page, the element may be in an iframe within 2 other iframes, so not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: @WeDoneLost Ofcoarse that makes a difference. Let's discuss the issue in details within the Selenium Chat Room.

Comment: Ugh, it doesn't let me because I'm new and don't have 20 rep points.

Comment: Thank you man, I was able to figure it out after research iframes a little better.  Still trying to find good ways of switching between iframes but going submit a new question.  Thanks again for the help.