# no href in anchor tag selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, anchor, angularjs-ng-href

Python Version 3.9.12, Selenium Version 4.8.0

Hi, I am trying to scrape this [link](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/en-ca/dining/)

Using Selenium Python

When you go to this link and press the **Search Times** button, you will see list of available restaurant.

```
#Search Button Click
search_times = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'finder-button.primary.ng-star-inserted')
search_times.click()
        
available = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/app-root/finder-layout/div/main/div/finder-list/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section')

#List of available restaurant cards
cards = available.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'finder-list-card')
```

Each `finder-list-card` is clickable since has an anchor tag with href and i found that:

```
<a _ngcontent-ysa-c53 finderlinkid class="anchor ng-star-inserted" title tabindex="0" target="_self" href="/en-ca/dining/disney-california-adventure/carthay-circle-lounge/" name="&amp;amp;lid=DLR_List_Dining_BarsLoungesReservationsAcceptedCarthayCircleLoungeAlfresco">
```

since it has `href` so I am able to get the link using `elem.get_attribute("href")`
But I don't need that link, there is button where time is mentioned as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Clk.png). I need that url because that will take to book the reservation (you'll probably see a singup page when you click that button)

```
<a _ngcontent-ysa-c55 class="offer ng-tns-c55-26 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0">
```

Since this anchor does not show any `href` so I am unable to get the link from `elem.get_attribute("href")`.

Is there any way I could find the hidden url behind that time button as shown in image.
Please suggest anyone. Thanks in advance

Comment: what's inside the `a` tag?