# How to scrape iframe inside possible shadow DOM with Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow

So I'm trying to scrap a a salesforce page and I have structure like this

```
<html>
    <div class="windowViewMode-normal oneContent active lafPageHost" data-aura-rendered-by="1235:0"
        data-aura-class="lafPageHost">
        <!--render facet: 1264:0-->
        <div class="oneAlohaPage" data-aura-rendered-by="1266:0" data-aura-class="oneAlohaPage">
            <force-aloha-page data-data-rendering-service-uid="396" data-aura-rendered-by="1269:0"
                force-alohapage_alohapage-host="">
                <div force-alohapage_alohapage="" class="iframe-parent slds-template_iframe slds-card">
                    <iframe force-alohapage_alohapage="" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true"
                        name="vfFrameId_1687293452916" title="Time Entry" allowfullscreen="true" lang="en-US"
                        allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *; display-capture *" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false"
                        src="./Time Entry _ Salesforce_files/saved_resource.html"></iframe>
                </div>
            </force-aloha-page>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

and the HTML goes on, I know that because I have the iframe I have to switch to it, but when I try

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')
```

I get an `NoSuchElementException` saying it cannot find it, I saw a `#shadow-root (open)` in a tag inside the `<iframe>` not sure if that could be the issue

#### EDIT

I found a way to get the iframe, I got the div just before it and then the iframe inside of it

```
iframeParent=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//[@id="brandBand_2"]/div/div/div[2]/div/force-aloha-page/div')
iframe = iframeParent.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')
```

but I don't know why it worked

Comment: Does this [iframe discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) and [shadow-root discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447) helps you?