# Selenium: how to get element in shadow root of html page code?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, metamask

I need to get the element of the button to connect the MetaMask wallet to the polygon network bridge using selenium.

the button I need to find:
[image]
But the button, as I understand it is hidden in shadow root of the html page.

If I find HTML code of the button with right click and 'inspect', I can try to copy it s X-Path.
When I paste it is: `/button`
That does not work:

```
metamask = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/button')))
metamask.click()
```

Results in an error. Text of these errors is every time the same so I will paste it in the end.

If I try to right click, 'inspect' and copy CSS-Selector it also does not work.
The CSS-Selector copied is: `button:nth-child(1)`
I can not get the button with this.

Now, text of the error which arises when I try to find the button by CSS-Selector or X-Path:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\selenium_airdrop_hunter\main.py", line 126, in <module>
    metamask = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/button')))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\selenium_airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B9A813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x00B2C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00A35358]
    (No symbol) [0x00A609A5]
    (No symbol) [0x00A60B3B]
    (No symbol) [0x00A8E232]
    (No symbol) [0x00A7A784]
    (No symbol) [0x00A8C922]
    (No symbol) [0x00A7A536]
    (No symbol) [0x00A582DC]
    (No symbol) [0x00A593DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DFAABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E3A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E3456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C251E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00B35F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00B32328]
    (No symbol) [0x00B3240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00B24FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76A100C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D77B4E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D77B1E+238]
```

A common error when selenium is unable to find and click an element

[Button element in HTML code of the page (better try to locate the element in html code yourself)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zplj.png)

How can I find and click this button with selenium?

UPDATE:
I found information on how to locate elements inside shadow root:

`shadow_element = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('w3m-modal').shadowRoot.querySelector('div').querySelector('div')")`

Yet still I can not make a path to my target button
Code above reaches one of divs inside of correct shadow root, yet can not grasp any element after following html comment:

`<!--?lit$702571791$-->`

How do I proceed and grasp elements that go after the comment above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<button>` element is within multiple [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447)

[image: w3m]

---

### Solution

To click on button with text **MetaMask** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('w3m-connect-wallet-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-desktop-wallet-selection').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-wallet-button').shadowRoot.querySelector('button > div > w3m-text.w3m-sublabel')")))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 2):

you first need to locate the element that contains the `shadow-root` using any strategy (XPath, CSS selector, name, etc).

In your case, this element would be the tag `<w3m-wallet-button name="MetaMask"`

```py
shadow_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'w3m-wallet-button[name="MetaMask"]').shadow_root

WebDriverWait(shadow_element, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'button'))).click()
```

Import the required modules:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

[UPDATE]:

- Various elements on this website are embedded inside the `shadow-root`.
- for example, your target/desired button is embedded in a **5-layer** nested `shadow-root`

Here's the complete working solution:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = "https://wallet.polygon.technology/?redirectOnConnect=zkEVM_bridge"

driver.get(url)
# click on the "Connect to a Wallet" button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.navbar__apps-section__auth__login"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("""document.querySelector('w3m-modal').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-modal-router').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-connect-wallet-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-desktop-wallet-selection').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-modal-footer').querySelectorAll('w3m-wallet-button')[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();""")
time.sleep(5)
```

- After clicking on the <kbd>Connect to a Wallet</kbd>, we wait for 1-2 seconds just to make sure that the overlay window is visibly present, although it appears very quickly.
- The used javascript query to locate and click on the desired button

  ```js
  document.querySelector('w3m-modal').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-modal-router').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-connect-wallet-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-desktop-wallet-selection').shadowRoot.querySelector('w3m-modal-footer').querySelectorAll('w3m-wallet-button')[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();
  ```

  will click on the very first wallet, if you like to click on the 2nd or 3rd wallet option, just simply replace the `querySelectorAll('w3m-wallet-button')[0]` with `querySelectorAll('w3m-wallet-button')[1]` or `querySelectorAll('w3m-wallet-button')[2]` respectively in the above-mentioned javascript query.

[image]

Comment: Results in the same error, selenium is unable to locate this element in such way.

Comment: @childoflogos7, please check the updated solution above.