# How can I locate element inside several shadow-roots

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, frontend

I need help locating the Xpath or CSS Selector of the download JSON  button on this page.

https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-main-public/query-builder?month=12&year=1962

I copied the selector via Chrome browser but it is not locating the button when I control find.

Xpath ->  `//*[@id="exportResultsButton"]`

CSS     ->  `#exportResultsButton`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is placed inside several `shadow-root`s, to get internal shadow root structure, you should get it's host first and then get `shadowRoot` property.

In your case you can write function that drills inside several shadow-roots.

1. 1st level has tag `app-container`
2. 2nd level has id `query_builder`
3. 3rd level has id `results`

`get_shadow_root` function gets shadow root from host, using JS executor.

`drill_into_shadow_roots` goes inside every provided selector from array, makes it host and gets `shadowRoot` property, so next iteration would start from new host.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

timeout = 10

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

def drill_into_shadow_roots(selectors):
    host = None
    _wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    for by, selector in selectors:
        host = _wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, selector)))
        host = get_shadow_root(host)
        _wait = WebDriverWait(host, timeout)
    return host


driver.get("https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-main-public/query-builder?month=12&year=1962")

selectors = [(By.TAG_NAME, 'app-container'), (By.ID, 'query_builder'), (By.ID, 'results')]
results = drill_into_shadow_roots(selectors)
WebDriverWait(results, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'exportResultsButton'))).click()
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a thousand times.