# Python to scrape a dynamic page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is the page I'm attempting to scrape:
https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/vancouver/server/no-namespace/ActionAPIBoth

I'm trying to get all the `//*[@id="Action_getURLParameter_S-anchor"]/div/div[1]/h3`, essentially all the api names.

But right now I can't even get the html of the dynamic page. I'm just trying to do that.

```py
url = "https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/vancouver/server/no-namespace/ActionAPIBoth"

chrome_options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options) 

driver.get(url) 
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

print("Page Title:", driver.driver) # works

# Did not work
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    print(element)
except TimeoutException as e:
    print(e)

# Did not work
driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

page_source = driver.page_source

with open("page.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(page_source)
```

The html that is saved has the header and footer and only a loading icon where the main content is.

I also tried waiting longer, scrolling down. But nothing is working yet.

Just wanted to see if there are any other things I could try.

Comment: If the data is loaded via ajax, can't you just call the same endpoint that loads the data?

Comment: Does this answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139185/how-can-i-accurately-locate-a-web-element-in-a-web-page-with-selector/77142201#77142201 In your case selectors array is `selectors = [(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'dps-app'), (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'dps-api-docs'), (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'api-content')]`