# Not able to access Reddit login button which is placed inside several shadow-roots

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

On Reddit.com when I click on Log In Button a Dialog Appears to fill the Login Details, but the Log In In Button on the Dialog is Not Accessible through any Locators. When I copy  various Locators using Chrome Browser for that WebElement and Verify them using the ctrl+f search, the browser not able to find it own generated Locator Path or Address. Other WebElements Work Fine. I have shown the Button on Attached Image. Any Help would be very Appreciated[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element placed inside several shadow-roots, to access them you should use js executor depends on your language.

You should go through each shadow host, get it's `shadowRoot` property and query for inner element.

JS script to get button is

```js
document.querySelector('shreddit-overlay-display').shadowRoot
.querySelector('shreddit-signup-drawer').shadowRoot
.querySelector('shreddit-slotter').shadowRoot
.querySelector('button.login')
```

example how to do it on Python

```py
js_script = """
   document.querySelector('shreddit-overlay-display').shadowRoot
   .querySelector('shreddit-signup-drawer').shadowRoot
   .querySelector('shreddit-slotter').shadowRoot
   .querySelector('button.login')
"""
login_button = driver.execute_script(js_script)
```

[Reference to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139185/how-can-i-locate-element-inside-several-shadow-roots/77142201#77142201)