# python/selenium: how to access button element in a slot under the shadow-root (shadow DOM)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom, shadow-root

I am new to the shadow DOM and I hope I can get help here. Many Thanks!

the link is: wertpapiere.ing.de/
Problem is from clicking the button to accept cookie.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfx90.png)

code until locate the shadow-root of this button:

```
baseurl='https://wertpapiere.ing.de'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(baseurl)
locB = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'dialogContent')]")
shadowrootB = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", locB)
locC=shadowrootB.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ing-cc-button-6610.cc-l0__button__accept') #ok
shadowrootC = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", locC) #ok
```

under this shadow root, the slot can be located:
b=shadowrootC.find_element('id','button-btg1c3gu3c') #OK

`<!---->       <slot name="icon-before"></slot>       <div class="button-content" id="button-btg1c3gu3c"><slot></slot></div>       <slot name="icon-after"></slot>       <slot name="_button"></slot>     <!----> <button tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" slot="_button" type="submit"></button>`

for the button, copy from the chrome:

```
 css:
```

ing-cc-button-6610.cc-l0__button__accept > button

```
xpath:
```

//*[@id="dialogContent-sjk4n7c2qu"]//ing-cc-button-6610[1]/button

```
bt=shadowrootC.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="dialogContent-sjk4n7c2qu"]//ing-cc-button-6610[1]/button') #NOK
bt=shadowrootC.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ing-cc-button-6610.cc-l0__button__accept > button') #NOK
bt=shadowrootC.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button') #NOK
```

then I see above this shadow-root there is another parallel shadow-root at the same level which has <div> of iframe. Is there any relation of here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtZ0g.png)

How to access this button using click() ?
furthermore any explanation on shadow-root/iframe and shadow-root/slot/button may help to better understand

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go to 2nd level shadow-root, first one is enough.

Just wait for consent modal presence, go inside 1st level shadow-root (like you did, that's fine) and then click on element with locator `[type=button]` which is root locator of button container.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

baseurl = 'https://wertpapiere.ing.de'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(baseurl)
locB = wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'dialogContent')]")))
shadowrootB = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", locB)
locC = shadowrootB.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type=submit]').click()
wait.until(expected_conditions.staleness_of(locB))
```

Comment: Many Thanks to you Yaroslavm, this is a fantastic solution. I am new in shadow DOM and from the google search recent days all result said that the element in nested shadow root can only be located layer by layer. May I ask  what reading material or link can you recommend for me to gain deep knowledge?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139185/how-can-i-locate-element-inside-several-shadow-roots/77142201#77142201 - reference to similar question how to locate multi-layer shaddow-dom (not your case, you need only 1 level)

Comment: More about shadow dom (how it works) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM