# Scraping div with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to select an element to click it on a page (https://twitchtracker.com/riotgames/games). The element is a selectable date on a calendar pop-up.

It is

`<div class="day unit in-range" data-time="1698822000000">1</div>`.

Is there any way to select the element using the `data-time="1698822000000"` element.

I've tried using By.CSS_SELECTOR but I always obtain a 'Unable to locate element' error.

Comment: Can you provide the selector you are using? Two possible issues: Element is not ready (not rendered) when Selenium tries to find it; Element is inside Shadow Root and you need to target this first.

Comment: I used: driver.findElement(By. CSS_SELECTOR("div[class='day unit in-range'] [data-time='1698822000000']"));

Answer (score 1):

Your element is placed in shadow-root, so to get it, you need to find it's host and go inside it by getting `shadowRoot` property.

Then you need to emulate js click as far as your element is not interactable.

[Reference to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139185/how-can-i-accurately-locate-a-web-element-in-a-web-page-with-selector/77142201#77142201)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

def click_js(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].click()', element)

url = ('https://twitchtracker.com/riotgames/games')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

host = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'easepick-wrapper')))

date_element = get_shadow_root(host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.unit.in-range')
click_js(date_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `get_attribute` function to get the `tag` value from the selenium web element like this:

```
element= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='day unit in-range']")
date_time=element.get_attribute('date_time')
```

Comment: thank you for replying! unfortunately running the first line gives me 

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='day unit in-range']"}

Answer (score 0):

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.day.unit.in-range")
date_time = element.get_attribute('data-time')
```

Comment: thank you for responding! I get this error too unfortunately :( selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.day.unit.in-range"}

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your site and the calendar days are inside a shadow root. Please try selecting the shadow root first (available for Selenium 4.1 and latest Chromium browser):

```
host_el = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.easepick-wrapper')
shadow_root = host_el.shadow_root
day = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-time="1699225200000"]')
```

You can also try this in the browser console, the following query selector will return null:

```
document.querySelector('[data-time="1699225200000"]')
```

This will return the element:

```
document.querySelector('.easepick-wrapper').shadowRoot.querySelector('[data-time="1699225200000"]')
```