# Shadow Dom elements with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

How can we write paths for Shadow Dom elements in selenium. I was able to write methods for elements which are inside 2 or 4 nested shadow DOM. But now I am facing elements which are nested under more than 8 shadow DOMs

[Example of Method for element under ShadowDom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM2EO.png)

I am looking for an easier way to write paths for ShadowDoms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I locate element inside several shadow-roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139185/how-can-i-locate-element-inside-several-shadow-roots)

Answer (score 0):

You can effortlessly locate the shadow DOM element by using 'Copy JS Path' feature.

[Copy JS Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhkUc.png)

Kindly refer the below link for additional information on how to use it with javascriptExecutor :

[How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)