# How to click on the shadowbox in selenium-python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create an automation program. I want to click on the "Accept Cookies" shadowbox on the given website.
Here's how I have tried to achieve this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get(r'https://www.studydrive.net/')

script = '''return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[aria-label="Accept All"]')'''
accept_all_btn = driver.execute_script(script)
accept_all_btn.click()
```

Here's the error that I get after following this approach:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I don't know, what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see aria-label on the button element.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get("https://www.studydrive.net/")
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"usercentrics-root")))

script = '''return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')'''
accept_all_btn = driver.execute_script(script)
accept_all_btn.click()
```

Simply wait for the element and then proceed to click the accept all button. No aria-label was specified so I used another attribute.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>Accept all</kbd> button is within a [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python/65055114#65055114)

[image: shadow-root]

---

### Solution

Tto `click()` on the desired element you need to use `shadowRoot.querySelector()`

[image: querySelector]

You can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.studydrive.net/")
time.sleep(5)
accept_all = driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector("#usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")''')
accept_all.click()
```

> PS: The cookie popup surfaces on the screen after significant amount of time, so you may have to induce some [waits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to locate the First name field within shadow-root (open) within the website https://www.virustotal.com using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864415/how-to-locate-the-first-name-field-within-shadow-root-open-within-the-website/62866838#62866838)
- [How to get past a cookie agreement page using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734432/how-to-get-past-a-cookie-agreement-page-using-python-and-selenium/65735009#65735009)
- [Unable to locate the Sign In element within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799036/unable-to-locate-the-sign-in-element-within-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-a/62803671#62803671)