# Element not found Selenium , site React

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, web-scraping

Selenium does not find the accept cookies button.

Tested: xpath, class and css

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSpY4.png)

[Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGtQC.png)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import csv

options = Options()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

navegador = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

navegador.get('https://app-vlc.hotmart.com/market/search?categoryId=25&page=1&userLanguage=PT_BR')
navegador.implicitly_wait(30)
sleep(30)
navegador.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cookie-policy-accept-all.hot-button.hot-button--primary").click()
navegador.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elem=navegador.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='hotmart-cookie-policy']").shadow_root
elem.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cookie-policy-accept-all.hot-button.hot-button--primary").click()
```

You need to find the shadow root and then find from there.

Since the above didn't work try this one.

```
navegador.get('https://app-vlc.hotmart.com/market/search?categoryId=25&page=1&userLanguage=PT_BR')
time.sleep(10)
elem=navegador.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='hotmart-cookie-policy']")
script='''return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector(".cookie-policy-accept-all.hot-button.hot-button--primary")'''
elem1= navegador.execute_script(script, elem)
elem1.click()
```

Comment: continues with error

https://prnt.sc/1oPVvV5ScRHo

Comment: oh it was shadow_root

Comment: error https://prnt.sc/t15WNzoy7s03

Comment: What version of selenium are you running?

Comment: 4.0 https://prnt.sc/bugzsj3GCFxR

Comment: So like these ones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177841/how-to-click-on-the-shadowbox-in-selenium-python/70180611#70180611