# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException error extracting element text from #shadow-root (open) using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, shadow-dom, queryselector

I'm am currently using selenium to take the product information from Sneider electric and this is currently the error I am receiving:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
no such element: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/main/div[5]/ul/li/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/product-cards-wrapper//div/ul/li[1]/product-card/article/div/div[1]/product-card-main-info//div/pes-router-link[2]/a/h3"}
```

Currently, the website I am trying to pull this information from is this URL:
https://www.se.com/us/en/product-range/63426-powerlogic-accusine-pcs%2B/?N=4176697776&No=0&Nrpp=12

The Xpath file is for the description of their products which according to my inspection and findings is this:

```
/html/body/div[2]/main/div[5]/ul/li/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/product-cards-wrapper//div/ul/li[1]/product-card//article/div/div[1]/product-card-main-info//div/pes-router-link[2]/a/h3
```

Any ideas??

Current Code:

```
def page_function():
    driver.get('https://www.se.com/us/en/product-range/63426-powerlogic-accusine-pcs%2B/?N=4176697776&No=12&Nrpp=12')
    driver.maximize_window()
    # gets the amount of items in the search bar
    print("Number of products:", 69)
    # for loop to read the product name and descriptions

    # product = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-item")
    # product = product.text
    # print(product)
    pr = "]/product-card//article/div/div[2]/div[1]/pes-product-price/p/span[1]"
    nam = "]/product-card//article/div/div[1]/product-card-main-info//div/pes-router-link[1]/a"
    des = "]/product-card//article/div/div[1]/product-card-main-info//div/pes-router-link[2]/a/h3"

    # des_path = "#search-items > .search-item .details > a > .row.pt-5.pb-sm-5 > .multilines-3.text-truncate-multilines.xs-single-col-8.col-12 > .font-weight-bold.text-dark"
    follow_loop = range(1, 70)
    for x in follow_loop:
        y = x
        if (x > 61):
            y = x - 60
        elif (x > 49):
            y = x - 48
        elif (x > 37):
            y = x - 36
        elif (x > 25):
            y = x - 24
        elif(x > 13):
            y = x - 12
        else:
            print("")
        if ( ((x % 13) == 0) ):
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
            next_arrow = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "page-links__arrow page-links__arrow--next js-page-link js-page-link-next")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_arrow)

        xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/main/div[5]/ul/li/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/product-cards-wrapper//div/ul/li["
        xpath += str(y)
        xpath += des
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        description.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath))
        xpath2 = xpath.replace(des, '')
        xpath2 += pr
        unit_price.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath2).text)
        xpath3 = xpath2.replace(pr, '')
        xpath3 += nam
        name.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath3).text)
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: use classes and Id in xpath - to remove all there `div` which can change when page add some elements.

Comment: if `product-card-main-info` is a class then it should be `*[@class="product-card-main-info"]`

Comment: maybe it needs longer `sleep` so JavaScript will have time to add elements to HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product description is within a [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python/65055114#65055114)

[image: schneider]

---

### Solution

Tto extract the desired text you need to use `shadowRoot.querySelector()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://www.se.com/us/en/product-range/63426-powerlogic-accusine-pcs%2B/?N=4176697776&No=0&Nrpp=12")
time.sleep(5)
description = driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector("product-cards-wrapper.hydrated").shadowRoot.querySelector("product-card.hydrated").shadowRoot.querySelector("product-card-main-info.hydrated").shadowRoot.querySelector("pes-router-link.description.hydrated a > h3")''')
print(description.text)
```

Console Output:

```
Active harmonic filter - 60 A 380..480 V AC - IP00 enclosure
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to locate the First name field within shadow-root (open) within the website https://www.virustotal.com using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864415/how-to-locate-the-first-name-field-within-shadow-root-open-within-the-website/62866838#62866838)
- [How to get past a cookie agreement page using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734432/how-to-get-past-a-cookie-agreement-page-using-python-and-selenium/65735009#65735009)
- [Unable to locate the Sign In element within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799036/unable-to-locate-the-sign-in-element-within-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-a/62803671#62803671)

Comment: Perfect this ended up working but is there a way for this to be for looped for all of the other items on the webpage?

Comment: @JorgeJurado-Garcia I've to look into your specific usecase. feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.