# How to insert a value inside a shadow root? Selenium WebDriver NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can i access this shadow root above and insert a value into "Pesquisar" placeholder?

I tried: [How to locate the First name field within shadow-root (open) within the website https://www.virustotal.com using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864415/how-to-locate-the-first-name-field-within-shadow-root-open-within-the-website)
Didnt work. Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')

[Print Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAMae.png)